# How to stay DRY in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, method-chaining

In jQuery is there a way of saving commonly-used function chains for referencing later, to maintain a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) coding style?

For example in the following code I'd like to reference the chain `.closest('.row').closest('div').remove();`:

```
$('#search-results .row .unsafe').closest('.row').closest('div').remove();
$('#search-results .warnings').closest('.row').closest('div').remove();
$('#search-results .textresults1:contains("Endpoint offline!")').closest('.row').closest('div').remove();
// lots more distinct selectors
```

Something like this:

```
var bye = ".closest('.row').closest('div').remove()";

$('#search-results .row .unsafe').bye();
$('#search-results .warnings').bye();
$('#search-results .textresults1:contains("Endpoint offline!")').bye();
// more...
```

My question solely pertains to reusing chains of functions in this manner - i.e. whether jQuery has a way of executing a function-chain stored as a string in a variable. I appreciate that any example of code could be rewritten to avoid the need for this, but that's a different question. I think there could be quite a few use cases for storing commonly-used function chains like this - e.g. for complex styling/animation routines perhaps.

<sup>[I know that the first selector could be modified to encompass all of the subsequent ones, but it is done this way for performance. `#search-results` contains tens of thousands of `<div>`'s, each with a dozen elements inside of them. This way the fuzzy searches are done last (i.e. loose text matching with `:contains`), after the previous selectors have already killed off a few thousand rows. Also, this particular code is taken from a Greasemonkey userscript I'm writing, so I do not have the option of removing these spurious results straight at the source, server-side - it's not my server/website]</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Basic encapsulation will do it perfectly:

```
function removeStuff(selector) {
  return $(selector)
    .closest('.row')
    .closest('div')
    .remove();
}
```

exported from [@Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey)'s now deleted comment.

Answer (score 3):

By Using a simple plugin you can use it like `.bye()`

```js
(function ( $ ) {
  $.fn.bye = function() {
    $(this).remove();
    //$(this).closest('.row').closest('div').remove();
  }
}( jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>click</button>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('button').bye();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @Kaiido That's a highly subjective take on the approach, not the answer, and this answer provides precisely what the original question asks for.

Comment: @tadman I didn't said anything that goes against your statement. Yes I do critique the approach, yes, this answer does answer the question as it is asked, and yes, it is a very bad approach for the exposed problem. Note that the approach given by HereticMonkeys avoids this GlobalScopeHell, so it was actually possible to answer the question at hand without offering the gun OP asked in order to shoot their foot.

Comment: @Kaiido If you've got something to say about the original approach you should comment on the question itself. Mohamed is answering the question as posed, not as it *should* have been posed.

Comment: @tadman Nope. The question is how do I tighten my screw, I thought of using a hammer but don't know where to find one. The correct answer is "use a screw-driver". Now, it doesn't hurt to have an answer "here is your hammer", but it is important to have at least a comment saying that it's not the solution for the current problem.